# Asking about when is the time for breakfast

Tags: grammar

Which of the questions below are acceptable when asking a clerk at a hotel about breakfast?

> When is the time for breakfast?
>
> When is the time of breakfast?
>
> What time is breakfast?

My teacher once used the last one. Is he correct?

Comment: Your teacher is correct.  The question can even be  "When's breakfast?"

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher is correct.

When you use the word **when** you don't also need to say "the time of" or "the time for".  The word **when** *refers* to time.  That is what it asks about.  It literally is a synonym for "what time".

So your teacher's example

> What time is breakfast?

is perfectly idiomatic.  Also perfectly fine is,

> When is breakfast?

Technically,

> What is the time for breakfast?

is also grammatically fine, but it sounds stilted and odd, while

> What is the time of breakfast?

which is also grammatical, sounds farcical, like someone is making mock of someone very pompous or parodying antique English.

Comment: "At what time is breakfast?" has always worked for me, too... or, if you want to dangle, "What time is breakfast at?"

Comment: If I *really* want to be pompous (in AmE), I'd use meal names as verbs. *At what time shall we breakfast? If late, perhaps we ought not lunch at all, and sup early.*